# Selenium IDE - How to create a JavaScript function relating to todays date?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am quite new to using Selenium IDE. I am trying to create a suite of regression scripts to use within our department. I am trying to figure out how to enter todays date + 180 days into a field using a JavaScript function.

Could anyone enlighten me as how to write that function? I am in the process of learning JavaScript but it is a long old process!

If you need any more information, just ask.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Dan

Comment: Have you considered using a date library, like moment.js?

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your reply. Forgive my ignorance but i haven't heard of that, could you please explain how to use this? Many Thanks,

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Simple JS solution will be something like,

```
var now = new Date();
var date = new Date(new Date().setMilliseconds(now.getMilliseconds() + (24000 * 180 * 60 * 60)));
console.log(now);
console.log(date);
```

This should print something like,

```
Mon Jan 19 2015 12:26:21 GMT-0500 (EST)
Sat Jul 18 2015 12:26:21 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Comment: From there, you can use `date.getDay()` to fetch the day @OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I have managed to get what i needed from the following JS:

```
Selenium.prototype.doTypeTenantDate = function(locator){

var dates = new Date();

dates.setDate(dates.getDate() + 180);

var day = dates.getDate();

if (day < 10){

day = '0' + day;
}

month = dates.getMonth() + 1;

if (month < 10){

month = '0' + month;
}

var year = dates.getFullYear();
var prettyDay = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
this.doType(locator, prettyDay);
};
```